# How to track how many times file has been opened in C#?

Tags: c#, file, directory, tracking

I basically need to be able to track how many times a file has been opened after being created in a certain directory. I want to keep track of the most used files on that particular directory.

Can I get the info on how many times a file has been opened since creation?

Comment: You might want to look at windows audit which can provide event log entry every time file is accessed: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making use of the **System.IO.FileSystemWatcher** class for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that You could make a registry entry that you keep the count in there